# PS3 / Dragon Age: Can I heal members outside my party?

Tags: ps3, dragon-age-origins

I'm currently in the Redcliffe village battle and although the first part was really easy, I'm struggling on the downhill area.

I've been using my mage to heal and create stuns but everyone slowly dies off that's outside my party.

Is there any way for me to heal members outside my party? I looked around and apparently in the PC version you can TAB to other members but the PS3 Controller obviously has no tab.

Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I just completed the level .. still curious if healing outside members is possible.

Comment: That particular area of that particular battle caused me to drop from "Normal" to "Casual" difficulty. I hadn't had a single death in my party up to that point, but I then had 3 party wipes at that point. So I think BioWare misjudged the difficulty there somewhat!
Casual was probably a bit too easy but I was playing more for the story + characters than the combat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this is unfortunately: nope, not on PS3. You can heal "neutrals" in the PC version but not the console version. Even large area healing spells like [Group Heal](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Group_Heal) will fail to affect neutrals.

Depending on your party makeup you can consider using some of the "battle control" skills such as [Threaten](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Threaten) and [Disengage](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Disengage) to keep neutrals alive. If your warrior is the most threatening character in the battle he/she will draw attention away from everyone else, including the neutrals. Provided you can keep the warrior alive under this kind of fire, you will probably notice the neutrals lasting longer.

Comment: Thanks, this is great to know. I've been building up my warrior to basically be a tank in that sense, so it's working out well as I gain more levels.

Answer (score -1):

I think the party members out of the party are always fully healed. When you choose to switch them I think they arrive with max HP.
Though I never needed to change them, just buy a lot of healing poultices and set tactics "When HP is <50% use healing item (lesser powerful)" you should have no problems at all ;)

Comment: You misunderstood my question, I am talking about in certain battles when you have additional units, as in the Redcliffe battle. Not the members I can swap with